# program to print transpose. program not working

Tags: c

I wrote the following program to print the transpose of a matrix. But I am not getting the desired result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Enter the number of rows");
    int r;
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("Enter the number of columns");
    int c;
    scanf("%d",&c);
    int x[r][c];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter the values");
            scanf("%d",&x[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\n",x[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            if (i!=j)
            {
                int k=x[i][j];
                x[i][j]=x[j][i];
                x[j][i]=k;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\n",x[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I believe the logic behind my code is correct but I am still not getting the desired result. Please help me with this. 
Sample input - output

```
Input elements in matrix: 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
Output

Transpose: 
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: please provide sample input and the output, along with the desired output

Comment: provided the sample input and  output

Comment: So it isn't printing out anything?

Comment: i am not getting the desired result (transpose)

Comment: My guess is you are switching elements, and then since you go through every element, you switch them again when you get to the one you switched to. To switch elements, when you see something already switched, you don't need to switch again

Comment: Think of only going through only half the matrix, as when you swap elements to the other half, those positions don't need to be visited

Comment: spoiler: `for(j=i+1;j<c;j++)` while swapping

Comment: @tyler not getting you

Comment: @Cherubim why did you take j=i+1?

Comment: just as @Tyler said... 'think of only going through only half the matrix'

Comment: Yep, you're doing 9 swaps, when you only need 3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are storing the value in the same array.

`int k=x[i][j];
 x[i][j]=x[j][i];
 x[j][i]=k;`

Suppose the matrix is 3x3. In first run of loop values of (0,0), (0,1), (0,2) will be interchanged by (0,0), (1,0), (2,0).

But when i will be 1 then (1,0) will again be replaced by (0,1). Similarly when i will be 2 the (2,0) with (0,2) and when i will be 3 then the (3,0) with (0,3).

This will happen for all the cases.

To correct this problem you have to make a new matrix and assign the values in that.

Replace your transpose logic with this code

```
 for(i=0;i<r;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {


            transpose[i][j]=x[j][i];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the Transpose in the same array.
You must take a separate array to store the Transpose.
or If you don't want to store, you can directly print by switching the values of Rows to Column and Column to Rows.

Try this: https://codewin.org/c-program-to-print-transpose-of-matrix-using-array/

Hope it helps!